# Symfony2 - Console commands, how can I setup environment configuration?

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to use the Symfony2 Console component (without the entire Symfony2 framework) and not sure on the best practice way to load specific configuration files based on my environment.

In my use case I am purely using the Console component (I can use others if needed) but not sure how to load a specific configuration file based on my environment.

```
<?php
// app/console
// Include composer autloader
$loader = require_once dirname(dirname(__FILE__)) . '/vendor/autoload.php';
require_once dirname(__FILE__) . '/AppKernel.php';

use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\ArgvInput;

// Determine which environment we are on
$input = new ArgvInput();
$env = $input->getParameterOption(array('--env', '-e'), getenv('SYMFONY_ENV') ?: 'dev');
$debug = getenv('SYMFONY_DEBUG') !== '0' && !$input->hasParameterOption(array('--no-debug', '')) && $env !== 'prod';

$kernel = new AppKernel($env, $debug);

// The following line won't work because composer loader doesn't implement "Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface"
$kernel->registerContainerConfiguration($loader);

$console = new Cli\Console($kernel);
$console->setCatchExceptions(TRUE);
$console->run();
```

---

```
<?php
// app/AppKernel.php
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel;
use Symfony\Component\Config\Loader\LoaderInterface;

class AppKernel extends Kernel
{
    public function registerBundles()
    {
        $bundles = array();
        return $bundles;
    }

    public function registerContainerConfiguration(LoaderInterface $loader)
    {
        $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml');
    }
}
```

---

```
<?php

namespace Tel\Cli;

use Symfony\Component\Console\Application;
use Cli\Command;

/**
 * Console application
 */
class Console extends Application {

    /**
     * Console constructor.
     */
    public function __construct($kernel) {
        parent::__construct('Application name', '1.0');

        $this->kernel = $kernel;

        // @TODO - Get these commands from DB/config file
        $this->addCommands(array(
            new Command\P1,
            new Command\P2,
            new Command\P3,
        ));
    }
}
```

Comment: the autoload file (vendor/autoload.php) is generated by composer to. Can you explain more. you want to get parameters from a command?

Comment: I am using the composer autoload file because I am only using some components from Symfony (e.g. Monolog and Command).

I know how to get the arguments and options for my commands but the issue is when I deploy this to test, UAT and production environment I want to load a specific file for DB/API URL configuration and the like...as per a regular website would do

Comment: $loader->load(__DIR__.'/config/config_'.$this->getEnvironment().'.yml'); will load different config file for each environnement. config_dev.yml, config_test.yml...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The app/config.yml is loaded by default, in addition another config file is loaded according to your environnement. 
You can specify the environnement of a command like that :

`php app/console myCommand --env=prod`

For accessing parameters, your command can extends abstract class `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand`, in this case you'll access to :

- a service : `$this->getContainer()->get('service_id')`
- a parameter : `$this->getContainer()->getParameter('parameter_name')`

Comment: This almost sounds like what I am after...although is app/config.yml still loaded by default if I am not using the Symfony2 framework bundle and just extending the "Symfony\Component\Console\Application" class...I can't see it mentioned anyway in the "Symfony\Component\Console\..." classes